# gunicorn terminated due to signal 9 and signal term

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

```
[2021-10-06 05:29:36 +0700] [497750] [WARNING] Worker with pid 497759 was terminated due to signal 1
```

What is the cause of signal 1? I can't find any information online. I checked the CPU and Memory usage there's still plenty left.

What is the cause of signal TERM? I thought it's the signal when we manually close gunicorn, but today I found out that gunicorn shuts down due to signal term even though I haven't used the machine at all.

How do I debug signals? Is it possible to find out when signals are fired or what caused them?

python version is 3.7.6, gunicorn version is 20.1.0

Comment: Hi, were you able to find anything? I am facing the same issue and couldn't find anything.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70792330/out-of-memory-killed-process-gunicorn-on-aws-lightsail